# Dealing with pointer argument in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-parameter

I'm using a library which has a function with the following signature:

```
void LED_stop_blink_task ( void * callback_parameter );
```

The actual parameter the void pointer stands for is a pointer to uint32_t, which is the number of the led on the board.

Is there a way to call this function without using a variable to hold the data ?
In my imagination it will be like

```
LED_stop_blink_task(&35);
```

or the only way is like this:

```
uint32_t led_num = 35;
LED_stop_blink_task(&led_num);
```

If you're asking why I want to throw the variable away, well, I'm just curious if it's possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On most platforms it's possible to simply stuff the `int` in a `void *`:

```
LED_stop_blink_task((void *)32);
```

Then in the function you can cast to `int`.

> An  integer  may  be  converted  to  any pointer  type. Except  as 
>   previously  speciﬁed,  the result is implementation-deﬁned, might not
>   be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
>   type, and might be a trap representation.
>
> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously speciﬁed, the result is implementation-deﬁned. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undeﬁned. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

In practice this will work on any POSIX-supported platform. For example TLPI says:

> Strictly speaking, the C standards don’t define the results of casting
>   int to void * and vice versa. However, most C compilers permit these
>   operations, and they produce the desired result; that is, int j ==
>   (int) ((void *) j).

Comment: @Mellowcandle not well, see my answer.

Comment: @Mellowcandle I tend to trust Michael Kerrisk :-)

Comment: Ok, this is a way, but what if I don't have access to the insides of the function, if only have the prototype of the library ?

Comment: @Mellowcandle In that case your hands are tied by the way the function interprets your argument.

Answer (score 1):

Cnicutar's answer is almost perfect; let me extend it with that it's not really portable - int is not guaranteed to be of the same size (or smaller) than a pointer, so you should use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` instead.